# How to write character arrays with whitespaces into binary files in c++? And how to read them?

Tags: c++, class, fstream, binaryfiles

Now I am doing my course project in University. I need help. I want to create a simple dictionary. And I am using binary file method to do so. In the following code I am trying to write lines of text which contains whitespaces too. But I am getting wrong output. Is there anyone who can help me to write texts with whitespaces into binary files and read them?

```
//These are global variables in my code
string sword;
string sdefinition;
```

Here's my class:

```
class Input
{
public:
    char word[50];
    char definition[300];
    void input()
    {
        cout << "Enter a new word: ";
        getline(cin, sword);
        sword.copy(word, sword.size() + 1);
            cout << "Enter the definition: ";
        getline(cin, sdefinition);
        sdefinition.copy(definition, sdefinition.size() + 1);
    }
    void output()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
        {cout << word[i];}
        cout << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(definition); i++)
        {cout << definition[i];}
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

This is my main function:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream a("data", ios::app | ios::binary);
    Input i;
    i.input();
    a.write((char*)&i, sizeof(i));
    a.close();
    ifstream b("data", ios::binary);
    b.read((char*)&i, sizeof(i));
    i.output();
    b.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read about serialization

Comment: Also read the ***complete*** technical specification of the `strlen` function, specifically what its major requirements are, then the specification for `std::string::copy`, and you should be able to figure out the problem all by yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem after reading reference for serialization, `std::strlen` and `std::string::copy`. Thank you so much :)